# Error MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. with VS 2019 16.8.3

Tags: .net-5

I installed the latest framework .net 5.0 and also upgraded VS 2019 from 16.6 to the latest 16.8.3. After this process, I created a new web app but got this error:

> Error MSB3644 To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
> (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your
> application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks WebApplication2 C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

I also repaired VS 2019 in case, it can resolve the issue but that didn't work either. Could you please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it's resolved..I uninstalled VS 2019 and installed it back.

Repair/Modify - nothing worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering this issue despite having the latest Visual Studio (16.11.2) and the latest .NET SDK (5.0.400).

The issue was that I had two different SDK locations in my PATH:

- C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk
- C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

The user specific installation came from the [Dotnet-install scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) and did not contain the .NET 5 SDK. Removing this from my path and restarting Visual Studio resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It was new version .NET
Update VS can help